# Why are my two struct-arrays not interacting with each other?

Tags: c++, arrays, struct

I've been trying to make it so an array of structs cease to move when they are on top of a different array of structs. So far however, the first array (AKA Zombies) only seem to interact with one of the second structs (AKA Holes).

When running, the program recognizes that a zombie is on top of all of the holes. However, will only stop them moving (by setting the struct alive member to false) if they are on top of one of two holes, instead of all three.

I did 5 tests, and they all show that none of the 'zombies' will stop moving (as they should) when they are over `hole[0]`. Only `zombie[0]` will stop moving in `hole[1]` and all three zombies will stop moving in `hole[2]`.

Also, for some reason even though the default setting for the 'alive' member is True, unless there is an `else` statement in the method, all but one zombie will simply disappear.

I've no idea why, but I suspect it is something to do with having a for loop within a for loop. Any help would be appreciated, whether given the precise answer or not :)

Main Method:

```
struct Player{
    int x;
    int y;
    int number;
    bool alive;
};

Player humanStart(Player Human);
Player zombieStart(Player zombie[], int difficulty, int mapSize, int level);
Player humanMove(Player human);
void zombieMove(Player zombie[]);
Player holePosition(Player hole[]);
Player humanCollision(Player zombie[], Player hole[], Player human, bool collided, int level);
void zombieCollision(Player zombie[], Player hole[]);

int main (){

int mapSize, difficulty, horde = 0, level = 0;
Player human = { 0, 0, 1, true};
Player zombie[27] = {0, 0, 1, true};
Player hole[27] = {0, 0, 1, false};
bool gameover = false;
bool collided = false;
srand((unsigned)time(NULL));

cout << "Please choose the size of the map. <10-32>" << endl;
cin >> mapSize;

    if (mapSize > 32 || mapSize < 10){
        cout << "Please enter a valid size between 10 and 32" << endl;
        cin >> mapSize;
    }

cout << "Please choose the difficulty level. <1-3>" << endl;
cin >> difficulty;

if (mapSize < 20)
    horde = 1;
else if (mapSize >= 20 && mapSize < 25)
    horde = 2;
else if (mapSize >= 25 && mapSize < 33)
    horde = 3;

level = (difficulty * 3) * horde;

for(int i = 0; i < 27; i++){

    zombie[i].number = level;
    hole[i].number = level;

}


HNDCONSOLE_H clrscr();
HNDCONSOLE_H createMap();

human = humanStart(human);
zombieStart(zombie, difficulty, mapSize, level);
holePosition(hole);

while(!gameover){

    for(int i = 0; i < hole[i].number; i++){            
        HNDCONSOLE_H gotoxy(hole[i].x, hole[i].y);
        cout << "O";
    }

    zombieCollision(zombie, hole);
    human = humanMove(human);           
    zombieMove(zombie);
    human = humanCollision(zombie, hole, human, collided, level);




    if(!human.alive)
        gameover = true;

}
system("pause");
}
```

Determines if the Zombie has collided with a hole;

```
void zombieCollision(Player zombie[27], Player hole[27]){


for(int i = 0; i < hole[i].number; i++){

    for(int z = 0; z < zombie[z].number; z++){

        if ((zombie[z].x == hole[i].x) && (zombie[z].y == hole[i].y)){

                zombie[z].alive = false;
                HNDCONSOLE_H gotoxy(20+z,20+z);
                cout << "ZOMBIE " << z << " DIED IN HOLE " << i << endl;            
        }           
        else
            zombie[i].alive = true;
    }
}
}
```

Prevents the zombie(s) from moving;

```
void zombieMove(Player zombie[27]){
int choice = 0;

for(int i = 0; i < zombie[i].number; i++){

    if(zombie[i].alive){

        rand();
        choice = 1 + (rand() % 4);

        if (choice == 1 && zombie[i].y > 1){
            zombie[i].y = zombie[i].y - 1;
        }

        else if (choice == 2 && zombie[i].y < 10){
            zombie[i].y = zombie[i].y + 1;
        }

        else if (choice == 3 && zombie[i].x > 1){
            zombie[i].x = zombie[i].x - 1;
        }

        else if (choice == 4 && zombie[i].x < 13){
            zombie[i].x = zombie[i].x + 1;
        }

            HNDCONSOLE_H gotoxy(zombie[i].x, zombie[i].y);

            cout << "Z";
    }

    else if(!zombie[i].alive){
    }


}

//return zombie[27];

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

int zombieCollision, the problem is in this line

```
zombie[i].alive = true;
```

for a start, the variable i is iterating over the holes, so it should not be used as an index to zombie.
Also, even if you change this to say zombie[z], it is still not going to work as it will make the zombie come alive if it is not over the *last* hole.

Your program will work without this line, assuming the zombies are marked as alive to start with. There is no need to set alive back to true in the loop.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed one problem, however that line was added to fix another problem.

For some reason, when I remove that line, the other zombies (except for 1) disappear...I've no idea why, nor why that line even fixes the problem :/

Comment: Ok for some reason, I've no idea why, but its not recognizing the zombie[].alive value as being set to True from the beginning, fixed it by 'reinitializing it' before the main while loop...wierd, but it works haha. Good ole C++....Thank a lot for the help I didn't spot that little mistake above, and would have taken me a while to try deleting that line :)

Comment: This code: `Player zombie[27] = {0, 0, 1, true};` creates a 27 length array of Player objects, but only initializes the first one to be alive. The initialization inside { } is not repeated for every entry in the array.

Comment: Oh right....I was hoping that didn't happen, but makes sense :) Thanks for explaining :) I reckon attempting to use vectors may be better than using arrays of which some don't get used haha.